# Unable to resolve module crypto in reactnative

Tags: react-native, npm, webpack, ethereum, web3js

I have posted this here  have created react-native app using

```
react-native init myapp
added web3 in package.json
npm install
react-native run-ios
```

but i am getting the error unable to resolve module crypto from web3-eth-accounts. Is there any way to fix this

unable to resolve crypto[image]

Answer (score 11):

Crypto is a node js module, when React Native is run - it uses Javascript Core. Crypto isn't include within this. When I installed crypto I used the following package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto

Instructions:

```
npm i --save react-native-crypto
# install peer deps 
npm i --save react-native-randombytes
react-native link react-native-randombytes
# install latest rn-nodeify 
npm i --save-dev tradle/rn-nodeify
# install node core shims and recursively hack package.json files 
# in ./node_modules to add/update the "browser"/"react-native" field with relevant mappings 
./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install
rn-nodeify will create a shim.js in the project root directory
// index.ios.js or index.android.js
// make sure you use `import` and not require!  
import './shim.js'
// ...the rest of your code
```

Import `shim.js` in your index.js file.

When you have done that crypto should be made available, if it still doesn't work I had to create a const in my App.js file like so:

```
export const cryp = require('crypto');
```

And import it into the components you need.

**UPDATE**

I've done a fresh build for this, I followed the below:

`react-native init TestApp`

Follow the instructions above for Crypto.

Linked:

`react-native link`

`react-native run-ios`

Comment: after executing the above steps and after running react-native run-ios i am getting CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Comment: What version of RN are you using, have you opened the project in XCode?

Comment: 0.57 and when i try to buid in xcode build is failing

Comment: I'll do a fresh build and check for you.

Comment: where to import  this file import './shim.js' in app.js? Also can you tell me where to add this line export const cryp = require('crypto'); in app.js ?. I don't have tsx file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181531/discussion-between-jrk-and-trinu).

Answer (score 4):

`react-native-crypto` don't work on recent react-native version `0.63.3` and react version `16.13.1`, any more.

I used `crypto-js` package. The version is `3.1.9-1` in my react-native app. It's working well.
You can add below line in `package.json` file.

```
"crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
```

Comment: Did you have to alias `crypto-js` to `crypto` somehow? I have `crypto-js` installed but metro still tells me it's unable to resolve crypto.

Comment: @ClaudioBrasser, I didn't renamed it. I used `crypto-js`.

Comment: are you importing `crypto` yourself or is it used by a library? In my case `crypto` is required by a library and I want to replace it by `crypto-js` since `crypto` is not available for rn.

Comment: hmm... I used the `crypto-js` to encrypt / decrypt a text.
If the `crypto` package is required by other library, I think you maybe change another library, or should customize the library so that it import `crypto-js`.

Comment: I shared the example code on https://github.com/dev0088/Whitings-RN

Comment: I met require cycle warn when using crypto-js 4.1.1:  WARN  Require cycle: node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js -> src/pages/index/index.tsx -> src/utils/hzxw-api-client.ts -> node_modules/crypto-js/index.js -> node_modules/crypto-js/core.js -> node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, it seems the crypto module is not supported by react native because when i install crytpo , it does not have an index.js file in the node_modules. so my problem came about when i was trying to use jsonwebtoken which uses crypto to encrypt data. so i uninstalled jsonwebtoken and switched to react-native-pure-jwt

Answer (score 1):

crypto is a node's library that works with the browser however we can use it with react native with some hacks mentioned below follow these steps and boom! you are ready to rock.

```
npm i --save react-native-crypto

==>  install peer deps 

npm i --save react-native-randombytes
react-native link react-native-randombytes

==>install latest rn-nodeify 
npm i --save-dev tradle/rn-nodeify

==>  install node core shims and recursively hack package.json files 
==> in ./node_modules to add/update the "browser"/"react-native" fieldwith relevant mappings 
./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain how to do the last line in your answer? How to add the shim? I have this in my bin/rn-nodify:

  if (toShim.indexOf('crypto') !== -1) {
    toShim.push('react-native-randombytes')
  }

Comment: Hello, @Bomber You don't have to add any files manually shim file will be automatically added in the root folder of your project by the last command `./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install`