# Cant find variable:Buffer in react native android application

Tags: android, react-native, buffer, bitcore

[image] 
[This error occures after resolving another error from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697108/unable-to-resolve-module-crypto-in-reactnative)

when It resolves crypto error but it creates new error for me how could I solve it?

Comment: Can you post the error? Are you using a fresh build?

Comment: Error screenshot is updated in my question

Comment: Have you included shim.js in your code?

Comment: Yes. I have. And it import in index.js

Comment: Do you have the code on GitHub?

Comment: no. Its not on github

Comment: Ok what's your set up, RN version, OS and are you building via react-native run command?

Comment: "react-native": "0.56.0"  OS: Linux, react-native run-android

Comment: I'll replicate and let you know. Hard for me you being Linux though!

Comment: OK sir. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did we find an resolution ?? I am trying QRCode package and I get this error.

Comment: @MushtaqueAhmed Try to use react-native latest version.